# Default select one item in the dropDownList Yii

Tags: yii, dropdownbox

I have a dynamic dropdown, data coming from the database.

```
 <?php $sel_id = $selected_id_array[0]->UPR_RelationType;?>
```

My dropdowm looks like this

```
 <?php echo    CHtml::dropDownList('RelationType_'.$pat_id[0]->PAT_ID,'U2U_RelationType',CHtml::listData(MasterTypeItems::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('MSTT_MST_ID'=>$relationship_type_array[0]->MST_ID),array('order' => 'MSTT_Name')), 'MSTT_ID', 'MSTT_Name'),array('id'=>'select','class'=>'relation_type','style'=>'width:50px'));
```

In this dropdown i have to select defaultly `$sel_id;`

for example am getting `$sel_id=5;` In the drop down i have to select 5th option as selected in yii. please give me any suggestion what i have to write in dropDown to select `$sel_id`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to achieve is a dropdownlist which already has a pre-selected option. If so, then this piece of code should work.

```
echo dropDownList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

where $select would be your default selected item.

More information can be found here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail

Comment: This is not the only method definition. You are looking at documentation for ```CHtml::dropDownList()``` and there is also ```CActiveForm->dropDownList()```

CActiveForm's ```dropDownList($model, $name, $data, $options);``` doesn't contain a parameter for a selected value like CHtml. Important to note in case someone is looking for the answer in a CActiveForm.